# VB.NET: my.computer.network.downloadfile - 0 file size

Tags: vb.net, download

I was using a call of

```
 My.Computer.Network.DownloadFile(Me.mUrl, Me.mDest, "", "", False, 100000, True)
```

for years and it worked perfectly. Suddenly, on some machines, this method saves a file with 0 file size. On same machines, it continues working (I cannot tell, which machine has wich OS right now, and I suspect, it is relevant to this problem). 
The files are accessible and available on the web server.

Do you have any idea what and why it could be? What may be done?

Comment: might it be something with the source  where the file(s) is/are coming from?

Comment: It might be. However, the c# version of this command works well ( WebClient webClient = new WebClient(); webClient.DownloadFile(new Uri(mUrl), mDest);) also the DownloadFileAsync works. I can download the files trough an internet Browser, I can download the files using the Linux wget. But the VB.NET is not working.

Comment: Just download it with the WebClient class then - the same way you're doing it in C# (System.Net.WebClient).